# How do I setup VPN to access computers on another network?

Tags: networking, vpn, setup

I m working in a private firm. We have two offices at different places. In one office there are a set of computers connected through LAN. These computers are assigned private IP addresses as given by ISP

Apart from that the ISP has also given a set of 5 public addresses. Now from the other office I want to access these computers through VPN. Please guide me the steps to setup the VPN.

Comment: You will probably get more help on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 URLs helped me a lot when I was trying to setup VPN.

http://www.wbitt.com/contributed-howtos/145-openvpn-over-virtual-private-server-vps.html

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=595436&highlight=howto+openvpn

Comment: thanx for your response

Comment: do you have some more links

Comment: the links are good..but i need some more information..basically i just want to know that if i want to connect to a particular Lan system then  how can i connect it..because that system has private IP and i can access the system only through public IP.

Answer (score 0):

For your configuration you need point-to-point VPN tunnel btw 2 locations.

Equipment depends of your budget

**Top level:**

Cisco Pix 501-506 series the best for small offices. most expensive. ($1000 and up)
You do need to know minimum cisco basic to configure.

WhatchGuard Firebox Edge E series ($800-$1000)
Web based configuration. Still expensive but easy to configure than Cisco

**Entry Level:**

Linksys RVS4000 series (about $250)

Netgear FVS318 series  (about $250)

Also check your other question you've asked.

I post some info for you